# Solving differential equation until periodicity

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations, periodicity

I would want to solve a differential equation in MATLAB

```
odeopts = odeset('MaxStep',dt);
[t,X] = ode113(@MyDiff,tSpan,X0,odeopts);
```

Here `dt`, `MyDiff`, `tSpan` and `X0` are defined earlier in the code. The problem is, that the discretisation step `dt` is very small, while the total simulation time `tSpan(end)` is very large. Furthermore, the solution is expected to become periodic from some time T with period `P`. Here, the period `P` is known a priori, while the time `T` is not.

What I would want to do is to automatically stop the ode113-solver when the solution `X` has become periodic, in order to save computational time. I would appreciate any thoughts on how I should do this.

My thoughts until now:

1. The first subproblem is how to stop the Matlab solver when periodicity is discovered. MATLAB has included the option to stop the ode113-solver by an event-function:

   `odeopts = odeset('MaxStep',dt,'Events',MyEventFcn);`

However, `MyEventFcn` has to be a function of `t` and `X` at the current time step. It seems impossible to determine periodicity by this information. The only way around seems to me to use a global parameter that includes the `X` values at all previous time up to two times the expected period `P`. However, this seems quite inelegant and inefficient to me, and I was hoping there is a better way.

2. The second problem is how to determine that the solution `X` is periodic with period `P`. At the moment I'm thinking that the best way is to use a threshold to the autocorrelation function, `xcorr(X)`, but I'm not certain yet about the details, so any suggestions here would also be useful.

Edit: I implemented a solution, pretty much following my earlier thoughts, using a global variable to keep track of the X-values and using xcorr to detect periodicity. After thinking a while, this actually seems the most straightforward way to do it.